# ViewModel Format Function

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I had to create this method `GetModelFormat` and wanted to see if there is a better way to format the view model that is being return. I would be happy for any kind of feedback since this is quite critical a part of my application.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            List<carmake> listofcarmakes = new List<carmake>();

            List<carmnodeltype> cartype = new List<carmnodeltype>();
            cartype.Add(new carmnodeltype() { TypeId = 1, Type="Red" });
            List<carmnodeltype> cartype1 = new List<carmnodeltype>();
            cartype1.Add(new carmnodeltype() { TypeId = 2, Type = "Green" });
            List<carmodel> carmodel = new List<carmodel>();
            carmodel.Add(new carmodel() { Modelid = 4, Model = "535d" , ListOfCarType = cartype });
            carmodel.Add(new carmodel() { Modelid = 5, Model = "535", ListOfCarType = cartype1 });

            carmake carmakes = new carmake();
            carmakes.MakeName = "BMW";
            carmakes.Makeid =1;
            carmakes.ListOfCarModel = carmodel;

            listofcarmakes.Add(carmakes);


            var listOfcarmodel = listofcarmakes
                 .Select(x => new CarViewModel
                 {
                     MakeName = x.MakeName,
                     CarModelViewModel = x.ListOfCarModel?.Select(z => new CarModelViewModel
                     {
                         Type = GetModelFormat(z.ListOfCarType)
                     }).ToList()
                 }).ToList();

            foreach (var obj in listOfcarmodel)
            {
                foreach (var vm in obj.CarModelViewModel)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(vm.Type);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    private static string GetModelFormat(IEnumerable<carmnodeltype> ListOfModel)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in ListOfModel)
        {
            if (item.Type == "Red")
            {
                if (item.TypeId == 1)
                {
                    builder.Append("Super Car");
                    builder.Append("<br>");
                }
                else if (item.TypeId == 2)
                {
                    builder.Append("<b>diesel engine</b>");
                    builder.Append("<br>");
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(item.Type);
                    builder.Append("<br>");
                }
            }

        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Model

```
class carmake
    {
        public int Makeid { get; set; }
        public string MakeName { get; set; }

        public List<carmodel> ListOfCarModel { get; set; }
    }
    class carmodel
    {
        public int Modelid { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public List<carmnodeltype> ListOfCarType { get; set; }
    }

    class carmnodeltype
    {
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    class CarViewModel
    {
        public string MakeName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<CarModelViewModel> CarModelViewModel { get; set; }
    }
    class CarModelViewModel
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: WRT your code: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions .